# Can a Windows Forms control have a Design Time-only property?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, properties, design-time

I wish to allow the user of my control to choose the licensing method for the control.  The choice comes from an enumeration, so they must choose one of the methods I have laid out for them.  This license needs to be chosen prior to the code executing at runtime.  Therefore I wish for them to selected a value at design time.  Furthermore I do not wish for this property to be writable at runtime, if that can be avoided.  Is there a way to make a property only available at design time?

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but using `System.Component.TypeDescriptor` and the related interfaces might work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can give a control design-time behavior by [creating a separate designer class](https://web.archive.org/web/20100402052134/http://en.csharp-online.net/Design-Time_Integration%E2%80%94Design-Time-Only_Properties) for the control. Since the control itself can only exist as an instance of your runtime, you can't really have a property directly on it which is set only at design-time (where would it get stored?). However, designer classes are only invoked and used by the designer, so you can encapsulate non-runtime behavior there.