# Is it possible to create a custom control property only settable at design time?

Tags: c#, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can a C# control have a Design Time only property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345019/can-a-c-control-have-a-design-time-only-property)

I want to create a custom control property that can only be set at design time is it possible ?

Comment: Thanks seems to be same question will read the article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes...  In your class, create a private field to identify if your property has been initially "set" or not.  Then have your standard property getter and setter.  However, in the setter, use the license manager to detect which mode you are operating under ... designtime vs runtime.  Then check.  Always allow if in Design-Time, OR if the field has never been set yet.  Once in, then set the flag as being set.  This will be needed since during the form designer's instantiation of the controls, it has to be set at least ONCE from the .Designer.cs code, but after that, ignore any attempts to change it -- via setting the flag.

```
    private Boolean IsCreated = false;

    private String myVar1;
    public String MyVar1
    {
       get { return myVar1; }
       set {
              if (LicenseManager.UsageMode ==  LicenseUsageMode.Designtime 
                    || !IsCreated)
              {
                  myVar1 = value;
                  IsCreated = true;
              }
    }
```

Now, you could still allow a change, but you would have to do it via a custom method created in your class since the "IsCreated" flag is PRIVATE and not PROTECTED for child-inheritance to muck around with.  You would have to clear the flag, then reset to the new string (or whatever ) value your property was to hold

Comment: thanks for the code snippet that will be much easier for me!