# C# How to expose a property based on the value of another property in a propertygrid?

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid

I have class with multiple properties. Sometimes a property (A) may be edited in a propertygrid. But sometimes property A may not be edited. This depends on a value of another property.

How can I do this?

EDIT:
I am sorry, I forget to mention that I want this in design-time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Runtime property models are an advanced topic.  For PropertyGrid the easiest route would be to write a TypeConverter, inheriting from ExpandableObjectConverter. Override GetProperties, and swap the property in question for a custom one.

Writing a PropertyDescriptor from scratch is a chore; but in this case you *mainly* just need to chain ("decorator") all the methods to the original (reflective) descriptor. And just override IsReadOnly to return the bool you want.

By no means trivial, but achievable.

---

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main() {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.Run(new Form { Text = "read only",
            Controls = {
                new PropertyGrid { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, SelectedObject = new Foo { IsBarEditable = false }}
            }
        });
        Application.Run(new Form { Text = "read write",
            Controls = {
                new PropertyGrid { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, SelectedObject = new Foo { IsBarEditable = true }}
            }
        });
    }

}

[TypeConverter(typeof(Foo.FooConverter))]
class Foo
{
    [Browsable(false)]
    public bool IsBarEditable { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
    private class FooConverter : ExpandableObjectConverter
    {
        public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(ITypeDescriptorContext context, object value, Attribute[] attributes)
        {
            var props = base.GetProperties(context, value, attributes);
            if (!((Foo)value).IsBarEditable)
            {   // swap it
                PropertyDescriptor[] arr = new PropertyDescriptor[props.Count];
                props.CopyTo(arr, 0);
                for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (arr[i].Name == "Bar") arr[i] = new ReadOnlyPropertyDescriptor(arr[i]);
                }
                props = new PropertyDescriptorCollection(arr);
            }
            return props;
        }
    }
}
class ReadOnlyPropertyDescriptor : ChainedPropertyDescriptor
{
    public ReadOnlyPropertyDescriptor(PropertyDescriptor tail) : base(tail) { }
    public override bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    public override void SetValue(object component, object value)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}
abstract class ChainedPropertyDescriptor : PropertyDescriptor
{
    private readonly PropertyDescriptor tail;
    protected PropertyDescriptor Tail { get {return tail; } }
    public ChainedPropertyDescriptor(PropertyDescriptor tail) : base(tail)
    {
        if (tail == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("tail");
        this.tail = tail;
    }
    public override void AddValueChanged(object component, System.EventHandler handler)
    {
        tail.AddValueChanged(component, handler);
    }
    public override AttributeCollection Attributes
    {
        get
        {
            return tail.Attributes;
        }
    }
    public override bool CanResetValue(object component)
    {
        return tail.CanResetValue(component);
    }
    public override string Category
    {
        get
        {
            return tail.Category;
        }
    }
    public override Type ComponentType
    {
        get { return tail.ComponentType; }
    }
    public override TypeConverter Converter
    {
        get
        {
            return tail.Converter;
        }
    }
    public override string Description
    {
        get
        {
            return tail.Description;
        }
    }
    public override bool DesignTimeOnly
    {
        get
        {
            return tail.DesignTimeOnly;
        }
    }
    public override string DisplayName
    {
        get
        {
            return tail.DisplayName;
        }
    }
    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetChildProperties(object instance, Attribute[] filter)
    {
        return tail.GetChildProperties(instance, filter);
    }
    public override object GetEditor(Type editorBaseType)
    {
        return tail.GetEditor(editorBaseType);
    }
    public override object GetValue(object component)
    {
        return tail.GetValue(component);
    }
    public override bool IsBrowsable
    {
        get
        {
            return tail.IsBrowsable;
        }
    }
    public override bool IsLocalizable
    {
        get
        {
            return tail.IsLocalizable;
        }
    }
    public override bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return tail.IsReadOnly; }
    }
    public override string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return tail.Name;
        }
    }
    public override Type PropertyType
    {
        get { return tail.PropertyType; }
    }
    public override void RemoveValueChanged(object component, EventHandler handler)
    {
        tail.RemoveValueChanged(component, handler);
    }
    public override void ResetValue(object component)
    {
        tail.ResetValue(component);
    }
    public override void SetValue(object component, object value)
    {
        tail.SetValue(component, value);
    }
    public override bool ShouldSerializeValue(object component)
    {
        return tail.ShouldSerializeValue(component);
    }
    public override bool SupportsChangeEvents
    {
        get
        {
            return tail.SupportsChangeEvents;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this also count for design time?

Comment: @Martijn pretty much; the problem, though, can be convincing the display to refresh the cached descriptors. But for IsReadOnly I suspect it'll work fine.

Comment: Do I also have to write a PropertyDescriptor? Or 'only' what you explained in the first paragraph?

Comment: And for what do I have to write a TypeConverter? What does it convert?

Comment: And on where do I place the attributes of the TypeConverter? On the properties or on the class?

Comment: @Martijn - TypeConverter is simply the first thing PropertyGrid looks at to ask "what does this have?". The [TypeConverter(...)] attribute goes on the type (class) you want to tweak.

Comment: Nothing happens when I override the GetProperties method. I throw an exception in the body, but it is thrown. Do I miss something? Do I need to write a PropertyDescriptor? And if so, Do I have to write a PropertyDescriptor for the same class as the TypeCOnverter?

Comment: *The exception is never thrown.

Comment: @Martijn - I'm not available at the moment, but I'll try to put an example together.

Comment: @Marc: When are you available?

Comment: @Martijn ah, sorry - slipped off the top of my head (lots of things on the go); one sec...

Comment: @Marc: Sorry for the late reaction but thank you for providing an example.

Comment: @Marc Sorry to awake a sleeping Q but how would you modify this sample to dynamically change the 'ReadOnly-ness' if IsBarEditable is changed at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes you are talking about WinForms.  If you would like to change one property's readonly state based on another, you will need to have your object [implement ICustomTypeDescriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163816.aspx).  This isn't a simple thing to do, but it will give you lots of flexibility about how your class is displayed in the propertygrid.

Comment: Not fully accurate; TypeConverter would be easier here, and you can also use TypeDescriptionProvider; so 3 options

Answer (score 0):

I've offered a similar solution in the past via [this stack solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377946/is-it-possible-to-create-a-custom-control-property-only-settable-at-design-time/4380034#4380034).  It makes use of a custom property, and conditionally ignores an attempt to change at design-time vs run-time, but I'm sure could be altered in the SETter by applying your own "criteria" to allow it being changed...